# How to get this ruby script running? (tested on ruby 2.0, my system has ruby 2.3)

Tags: ruby

I am not sure how to solve this.

The developer calls for ruby 2.0, and the dante gem.
My env has ruby 2.3 and I installed dante.

At run time, it throws as shown below.

How to resolve?

```
[root@localhost newrelic_redis_plugin-1.0.1]# ./newrelic_redis_agent -d
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from ./newrelic_redis_agent:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you install bundler too?

Comment: Apologies, what is bundler? (ruby is not my party...)

Comment: Bundler is a Ruby gem package manager. `gem install bundler`, and then `bundle install`, and then try to run your script again.

Comment: http://bundler.io/

Comment: @Casper Got it! that solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go inside your app directory and type: gem install bundler
If it does not work try: sudo gem install bundler
...but generally you can do it without sudo

If it does not fix the case then probably you have multiple ruby version installed.

If you are using RVM, you probably need to run:
rvm use system
to set the version of ruby to use.
See http://rvm.io/rubies/default
ruby -v
will tell you the version you are currently using.